# Issue with SimpleDateFormat's milliseconds

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat, milliseconds

I tried this snippet code and the output is very surprising. Why the output is different from the input? Did I make a mistake or is there a problem with SimpleDateFormat?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSS");
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse("2013-04-18-19.01.33.080");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // output: 2012-04-18-19.01.33.80
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT:** In fact, I checked my code and I wrote `yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.S` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSS`. It was a stupid mistake. Thanks all for your answers.

Comment: I've tested your code snippet and it runs fine for me using version 1.6. `dd` is correct for the day of the month too.

Comment: Dude, I get exactly the same output as input. Works alright. Which means your input parameters are correct too. Can you post the full class code just for clarity ? Please also mention your java version as mentioned by Steven, Thanks,

Comment: http://ideone.com/FDSlWN

Comment: The code as posted also works for me. I'm using JDK7 on Windows 7.

Comment: @pith `It was a stupid mistake` - and that is why you should post a SSCCE with every question, not just a couple of lines of code. We don't have time to waste, guessing what you may or may have not done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This works fine for me](http://ideone.com/FDSlWN), If it doesn't work for you try setting `Locale` explicitly

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: I would have upvoted, but I should not have to leave this website to see your 6 line test program. Post the code here.